# MacBook Pro screen dimming problems after EFI 2.3 update

Tags: macos, macbook-pro

I recently updated my MacBook Pro to the latest firmware: EFI 2.3. Since then when my screen dims from idleness (while plugged in), it takes at least 5-10 seconds to come back on after I touch the trackpad, keyboard, or mouse. Everything worked fine before the EFI update.

Has anyone else encountered this problem? If so, are there any solutions?

Comment: I also have this problem, but un-dimming can take even longer. I, too, had no problems before the update... No solution from me, but at least you know you're not alone, right?

Comment: I also have the exact same problem. Have you found a fix yet?

Answer (score 1):

This is what I did and it worked for me:

> 1.Shut down the computer.
>
> 2.Plug in the MagSafe power adapter to a power source, connecting it to the Mac if >its not already connected.
>
> 3.On the built-in keyboard, press the (left side) Shift-Control-Option keys and the power button at the same time.
>
> 4.Release all the keys and the power button at the same time.
>
> 5.Press the power button to turn on the computer.
>
> Note: The LED on the MagSafe power adapter may change states or temporarily turn off when you reset the SMC.

Comment: The steps to reset SMC depend on the Mac you have: [Intel-based Macs: Resetting the System Management Controller (SMC)](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht3964)